# Install CKAN in a cloud vm with private IP

Tags: ckan

I installed CKAN in a cloud server with private ip `a.b.c.d`. To access the web site,  I configured a port forwarding rule from public ip `e.f.g.h:10100` to `a.b.c.d:80`. Moreover, I deployed CKAN with Apache and Nginx following the [Deploying a source install](https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.8/maintaining/installing/deployment.html#deploying-a-source-install) instruction.

Now I can access CKAN home page with `http://e.f.g.h:10100`, however the login process will redirect the page to `http://e.f.g.h/user/login...` which is not accessible because of the missing port in the url.

In `production.ini` file, I have configured `ckan.site_url = http://e.f.g.h:10100`.

What do I miss in the configurations (e.g., apache, nginx or ckan production.ini)?

Comment: Its a pain, but for testing you can add the ports to the URLs in the browser address bar manually and hit enter. Login and logout need it done twice due to redirects. I did get this working once as you're wanting but cant recall what I did anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 files to edit in order to let CKAN realise the 'public address'

1. ckan.site_url in production.ini
2. CKAN_SITE_URL in .env

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me where the `.env` file is? My VM us running with Ubuntu 18.04 and installed CKAN directly from source.

Comment: I am using the docker setup. the .env is in ckan/contrib/docker. if you do not see .env, you probably can look for .env.template which you can duplicate and use as .env just `cp .env.template .env` and add/modify the variables according to your setup.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think `.env` file is not needed when installing CKAN from source (not with docker compose).  `/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/config/environment.py` will read the environment configurations from `production.ini`.  By testing today,  I notice the problem is that the web page is redirected to `http://public-ip/user/logged_in?__logins=0&came_from=%2Fuser%2Flogged_in` after login or logout.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is same as this [#4129](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/4129). So far it hasn't solved yet. As a workaround, my suggestion is set public IP to e.f.g.h:80 and forward to private IP a.b.c.d:80. If you were trying to run CKAN with https, then set public IP to e.f.g.h:443 and forward to private IP a.b.c.d:443.